# Read a specific byte from binary file

Tags: java, io, byte

I am trying to figure out how to get to a specific byte in a binary file using java. I've done a ton of reading on byte level operations and have gotten myself thoroughly confused. Right now I can loop through a file, as in the code below, and tell it to stop at the byte I want. But I know that this is ham-fisted and there is a 'right' way to do this.

So for example if I have a file and I need to return the byte from off-set 000400 how can I a get this from a FileInputStream?

```
public ByteLab() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        String s = "/Volumes/Staging/Imaging_Workflow/B.Needs_Metadata/M1126/M1126-0001.001";
        File file = new File(s);
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        int read;
        int count = 0;
        while((read = in.read()) != -1){          
            System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(count) + ": " + Integer.toHexString(read) + "\t");
            count++;
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) for the job. You can set the offset by the [`seek()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek%28long%29) method.

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r");
raf.seek(400); // Goes to 400th byte.
// ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`skip()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#skip%28long%29) method of FileInputStream to "skip n bytes".

Though be aware that:

> The skip method may, for a variety of reasons, end up skipping over
>   some smaller number of bytes, possibly 0.

It returns the actual number of bytes skipped, so you should check it with something like:

```
long skipped = in.skip(byteOffset);
if(skipped < byteOffset){ 
    // Error (not enough bytes skipped) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`RandomAccessFile`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375118/reading-buffered-binary-file-with-seek).