# How to only get the first 8 bytes from a file from a DataInputStream java

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, byte, datainputstream

Currently writing a java swing program. which gets all files from a drive and checks the binary signature. But i only want the first 2-8 bytes of the file to speed to program up. Tried most solutions already available but none work with what i have already coded.

Current Code:

```
 public void getBinary() {

    try {


        // get the file as a DataInputStream
        DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

        try {

            // if files are avaliable countinue looping and get bytes / hex 
            while (input.available() > 0) {

                // build  a hex string from the bytes and change to uppercase 
                sb.append(Integer.toHexString(input.readByte()).toUpperCase());


                // need to get the first couple of (8) bytes 
            }



        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        // print the hex out to command 

        //  System.out.println(sb.toString());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
    } 

}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem, what do you mean with the solutions you tried are "not compatible"? You already know how to read a byte with `readByte`, so what's stopping you from reading more than the first byte?

Comment: The code reads the bytes of a file yes but i need a 'byte limit' that only reads the first 8 bytes of a file not all 2000 bytes and i do not know how to do this.

Comment: Why not `readFully()` with an eight byte buffer?

Comment: byte[] buffer = new byte[8];       input.readFully(buffer); does not work it removes the first 8  bytes

Comment: maybe this helps you.
[this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11545039/read-a-specific-byte-from-binary-file)
[this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4375118/reading-buffered-binary-file-with-seek)

Comment: while ((input.read(b, 0, b.length)) != -1) { } tried this but just loops: 888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888

Comment: @JasminC It *reads* the first 8 bytes, which is exactly what you said you wanted. Unclear now what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

works perfect for me, and may help others too!!!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8SU5A.png